# Trying to change from mouseover to click

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the menu here from mouse over to a on click event:

http://jsfiddle.net/snoffoz/kBb2m/24/

From a

```
.bind('mouseover'...
```

to:

```
.bind('click'...
```

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/snoffoz/kBb2m/25/

Why cant it be this easy?

Comment: @ubercooluk: It is opening for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this...
I this what you want??
http://jsfiddle.net/kBb2m/41/

Answer (score 3):

Since you also want to be able to hide it (like you were doing on mouse enter and leave), you can use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which will show on first click and then hide on second and so on:

```
$('.jsddm > li').toggle(jsddm_open, jsddm_timer);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kBb2m/33/)**

Comment: Sarfraz this is great, thanks! 

Just a quick second question. How do i make the menue stay open until i click on another main menue point? So if i click on a sub menu point it will still be open.